Changing cursor position in Python not working
I want to move the cursor's position in Python, but it's not moving correctly.
def movecur(self, x, y):
    sys.stdout.write(f"\033[{y};{x}H")
    sys.stdout.flush()
   

If I run:
for i in range(100): print()
movecur(0, 0)

it will just send me to the top of the currently visible screen, not the very top. Any fix? I don't really want to use the Curses module.
That is: if I print 100 lines, and move it to 0,0, it moves the cursor to the top of currently viewed lines, meaning if I scroll up, I'm still at the bottom

What do you mean by "the top of the currently visible screen, not the very top"? How are those two different?

If I print 100 lines, and move it to 0,0, it moves the cursor to the top of currently viewed lines, meaning if I scroll up, I'm still at the bottom.

The ability to scroll up is something your terminal program gives you. Think of an actual VT100 or similar terminal. When text scrolls off the top of the screen, where does it go? Away. It goes away. The terminal program you're using is an emulation of that sort of terminal.  It has some extra features (such as being able to see what has scrolled off the screen) but it still has many of the limitations of the actual terminal it is emulating.

Yes - that is how terminal ANSI control sequences work: any cursor positioning, text, writting or other changes only affect the visible window.
Although there is an ANSI sequence to scroll down the display (f'\x1b[{y}T'), it will fill the new lines at the top of the screen with blank lines, not with the buffer that had scrolled up.
ANSI codes simply don' help you manage the text buffer that goes to the terminal  - what is off the screen is "gone" when operating in this layer.
Your options are interacting with the terminal contents using other layers  - either learn about the readline module and check if you can acheve what you intend using it, or create a fully managed TUI using curses (I wouldn't recommend it due to its clumsy API) or textual, a modern TUI framework which can help creating a really nice app.

Thanks for the response. Is there any other way to move the cursor besides external libraries? Thanks!

(note that "readline" is shipped with Python, though) - you have to take care yourself of what is on the terminal - that is hard, because printing "logic" lines that can be wider than the screen will take more than "physical" lines - but if only need to get back to start, and not select an arbitrary line: you have to create class that will annotate everything that is printed - (you can create a write method in a class, and use that to record the internal buffer before forwarding to stdout.write) - then when resetting the screen, home the cursor to (0,0) and print the buffer contents.
